# Visual Studio Component Tab

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, xbap

I am using visual studio 2012, and I made a WPF Browser application. I want to add some components (BackgroundWorker) but I don't see the component tab in the Toolbox. Should I change some configurations to see it? How can I view the component tab?

Answer (score 0):

if  you create custom controls  or  something else inherited from controls class you can use and add to form your controls programmatically but if  visual studio dose not appear  your component 
or controls references in toolbox u most be implement designer per each controls